# How can I import Chrome Canary's colored emoji feature to Chrome Stable

Tags: google-chrome, unicode

Chrome Canary renders Unicode Characters and special symbols into a colored format.

[image: Unicode Characters rendered in Chrome Canary]

While the stable version of Chrome renders these characters as simple glyphs.

[image: Unicode Characters rendered in Chrome Stable.]

I have searched a lot and have not found any relevant topic or discussion on how to import this feature to the stable chrome.

So it will be very helpful if someone can tell me if this is possible.

PS: I am not an advanced developer, I just seek to extract this feature.

Answer (score 1):

The change in rendering is due to the [fixing of this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333011). You can either wait for the patch to land in a stable release (around six weeks), or back-port the patches.